# Rosdep Yaml Exact Folder

Tags: pcl, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to specify the exact location of my PCL-1-7 installation in a *rosdep yaml* file? I've installed PCL from source.

This is the ROS installation error related to it:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
pcl_conversions: No definition of [libpcl-all] for OS [fedora]
pcl_ros: No definition of [libpcl-all] for OS [fedora]

I've tried with the yum pcl packages in Fedora but they don't seem to provide the right PCL version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108136/rosdep-yaml-exact-folder/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep interacts with package managers only.  So you cannot point it to a specific file/folder.

You can override the rosdep rule by creating your own rosdep file, which will set the rosdep resolution to an empty list if you want to manage the dependency manually.

When you have the file add it's path to your rosdep sources in /etc/ros/rosdep/

Then rosdep will not try to install pcl for you.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-12-09**:
Empty list = []? Can you give an example?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-09**:
Exactl. https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml#L1900 is an example

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-12-10**:
Thanks. That worked fine.